# Cannot pass sprite to function in cocos2dX

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I created a new cocos2dx ios project and succeeded to build and run it on ios simulator. But when I try to add a function like

```
void setImageSize(cocos2d::CCSprite *image, cocos2d::CCSize size);
```

I got this error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"HelloWorld::setImageSize(cocos2d::CCSprite*, cocos2d::CCSize)", referenced from:
  HelloWorld::initPhysics() in HelloWorldScene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm new to cocos2dx.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what you posted is a function declaration, did you maybe not implement the function or did you implement it without the HelloWorld:: prefix or with a different set of parameters? Post the entire implementaton and how you call the method plus any compiler warnings.

Comment: Yes. I didn't add the HelloWorld:: prefix. Thanks

Comment: in that case you created a C function, write it as HelloWorld::setImageSize(...